# Why is the penance for killing a Shudra relatively small?

Tags: mahabharata, varna, vyasa, shudra, vaishya

Mahabharat Book 12 Section CLXV Line says

> Having slain a Vaisya one should perform such a sacrifice for two years and make a present of a hundred kine with one bull. Having slain a Sudra, one should perform such a sacrifice for one year and make a present of a hundred kine with one bull. **Having slain a dog or bear or camel, one should perform the same penance that is laid down for the slaughter of a Sudra**.

According to the above shloka, the penance for killing the Vaisya and Shudra are as follows:

Vaisya: penance for 2 years + 100 kine + 1 bull

Shudra: penance for 1 year + 100 kine + 1 bull

Q1: Why the penance for slaying a Shudra is less?

Q2: Why is the penance for killing a Shudra equal to the killing of a dog/bear/camel? (refer to the bold text in the shloka above)

Comment: 2) Refers to killing all those animals, not just one. Killing lots of animals = do the penance for killing a shudra. Shudras are tamasic like animals. See Manusmriti 12.43: "Elephants, horses, Śūdras, Mlecchas, lions, tigers and boars—represent the middle state of tamas."

Comment: 1) The penance for each caste is always lower than the caste above it, starting from brahmana -> kshatriya -> vaishya -> shudra, etc. due to holiness of the caste. Killing brahmins is more sinful than killing kshatriyas, and so forth.

Comment: @Ikshvaku seems unfair

Comment: It's not unfair. Is killing the president a worse offense than killing a coffee shop manager? Yes. Is killing a doctor or lawyer worse than killing a toilet cleaner? Yes. Same concept.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. Please take a [TOUR](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour) of this site to get acquainted. Further, kindly visit [How does a new user get started on Hinduism SE?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). For more info please do visit: [the HSE Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help). Have an enriching journey!!

Comment: @Ikshvaku yes killing is killing. doesnot matter doctor or toilet cleaner.

Comment: Lol no. Consider this: is killing a human worse than killing an animal? Is killing an animal worse than killing an insect? Do you see no difference between killing a guru or acharya and killing a bug? Would you feel the same killing your mother when you kill a bug? It's far, far worse to kill a guru or a king (regicide). That's why the king/president has so many bodyguards and must get his food tested for poison; not the toilet cleaner.

Comment: @Ikshvakubut we r talking about humans heree

Comment: Just like within animals, killing a cow is worse than killing a rat or an insect, in the same way, within humans, there is also division. Killing the king of the country will cause massive devastation across the country. Killing a street sweeper won't.

Comment: there is no point in defending an archaic inhumane rule. I dont think anybody here will do that. At max, a rationale can be provided, not a justification. A rationale can be... at that time life of a brahmin was considered to be more valuable that that of a shudra. In modern day, if you kill a big minister then apart from IPC 302, other charges will also be filed on you like sedition, harming a govt employee, etc etc. You will get a strong punishment. Whereas if you kill a common man, not so much. Case in point: Godse.

Comment: @ConfusedSimpleton yes and even within humans some jobs are more valuable and important and some expendable, hence why in olden days a doctor made more money and a farmer was expendable this is common logic lol. Now keep in mind a Shudra is allowed to defend himself from anyone even if a Brahmin attacks him, but Shudras also died at the hands of other Shudras as infantries in wars, so likely why the penance was small.

Comment: Killing in general even regarding insects is unavoidable, but seen as impure.